# Adding a OnclickListener to ImageViews inside a HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, onclicklistener, horizontal-scrolling

This question may have been asked before but I seem to not make much `progress`.

Basically I want to add an `onclicklistener` to my **`HorizontalScrollView`** that expands the `image` when pressed.

Here's the current code in the **`XML`** file:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/firstscrollview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp">

      <LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/firstlinear"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:orientation="horizontal" >

             <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/Cercie_button"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/image"/>
```

I've been trying out different things but I can't seem to get it to work, if anyone knows or can find a good example it would be very much appreciated!

Comment: add it in onCreate method in MainActivity

Comment: an alterative solution would be a `ImageButton` instead of image view. `ImageButton` can implement the onClick xml attributes on the layout.xml

Answer (score 0):

Try this .

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    ImageView Cercie_button = findViewById(R.id.Cercie_button);
    Cercie_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // do something here
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if i am not getting it wrong then what so difficult in it you have to just do this in your on create method

```
ImageView btn = findViewById(R.id.Cercie_button);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //write what you want to do
    }
});
```